# Vue.js: Why does $el return a text node

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I do have the following code:

```
<template>
    <custom-child></custom-child>
</template>

export default class Custom extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$el);                    // Returns a text node (with an empty content)
    console.log(this.$el.nextElementSibling); // Returns a element representing my custom child
  }
}
```

I am quite confused why would I need to use `nextElementSibling` as I expected `$el` to return an element directly.

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows.

**wrong**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

**correct**

```
<template>
  <div>
  　<div>...</div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

OR

**wrong**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

**correct**

```
<template>
  <div>
  　<div>...</div>
    </router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

OR

**wrong**

```
<template>
  <!-- comment -->
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

**correct**

```
<!-- comment -->
<template>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

If you do not use a "div" tag just inside the "Template" tag, you will get the same problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).